# c# strongly typed dataset whose table adapter is not returning expected result

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, dataset, tableadapter

I have a C# application (using VS 2010 premium) implementing a strongly-typed dataset that's connected to an MS Access 2003 database. I am implementing a table adapter within this dataset whose SQL script is:

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Created By]
FROM [Table Group]
WHERE [Created By] = ?
AND [ID] IN (SELECT [Group ID] FROM [Table Clustering] WHERE [Cluster ID] = ?)
ORDER BY [Name]
```

problem is it does not return anything but supposedly it should (I have sample data in my database). I already tried implementing the same script within MS Access (replacing the ?s with real data) and it returns the data I expect.

I experimented by removing `"WHERE [Cluster ID] = ?"` in the embedded SELECT statement, and it returned data but that's not what I need.

I also did another experiment by replacing the ? within the embedded SELECT statement with an actual [Cluster ID] and it returned data, but again that's not what I need.

So what's the problem of the SQL script within the table adapter? Is it capable of implementing a SELECT within a SELECT? moreover, is it capable of implementing a ? in a SELECT within a SELECT? how?

thank you! =)

[image: The strongly-typed dataset I was taking about]

[image: The SQL builder I am using to create the table adapter]

so as expected, IDE automatically generates a method (to retrieve data) for the table adapter i did, ergo i do not need to manually create an SQL script within the code... for everyone's info (in case you're not familiar), the method generated asks for two parameters (as expected), one for [Created By] and one for [Cluster ID]... from here on, please refer to my problem i posted above. :D

Comment: Can you provide a sample schema and some data to help recreate this scenario?  Also, what code are you using to pass these parameters?

Comment: Can you not just do `WHERE [Created By] = @CreatedBy` and do a `Parameters.AddWithValues(@parameter name, @parameter value);`..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE think the code might be  auto generated.

Comment: the OP will need to show the code otherwise we are all just taking shots in the dark here..

Comment: just to emphasize, I am using strongly typed dataset, and I am using the dataset designer in creating a table adapter... I am not using any SQL scripting within my codes to make it look cleaner and more organized... If i will put SQL script within my codes, I would do that as my last option which I hope is not the case

Comment: so as expected, IDE automatically generates a method for the table adapter i did, ergo i do not need to manually create an SQL script within the code... for everyone's info (in case you're not familiar), the method generated asks for two parameters (as expected), one for [Created By] and one for [Cluster ID]... from here on, please refer to my problem i posted above. :D

Comment: @Remou the FillByAssigned method (encircled in red in screenshot above) was automatically generated by the dataset designer and it takes care of the parameter ordering, so i just supply data to those two parameters but, as i stated above, data is not being returned which should not be the case :(

Comment: You can try replacing  the  `?` as `@parametername`  e.g. `@CreatedBy` and  `@ClusterID`  in the query..  (by editing the query in designer).the code generator will interpret them as parameters to the query. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an IDE bug.  Specifically, you have two params so param1 and param2 in that order.  You would think that the "?" placeholders are in the same order but when you execute the query and the IDE asks you to fill in values, the last "?" is the first param (Cluster ID) and the first one (CreatedBy) is the second param.  This picture shows you what I mean:

[image: VS2012]

In the image, ID is the first line and Event Count is the second line even though the TableAdaptor has them as Event Count first and ID second.  I didn't try passing the params via a program but it seems like a bug that the IDE would work this way.